# How to edit the code generation of getters in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-settings

How to edit the code generation of getters in `Android Studio`, which are generated via hot keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> ? In which folder are the files which are spelled out in the instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new getter/setter code generation templates by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, selecting `Getters and Setters`, then choosing the ellipses (<kbd>...</kbd>) and pressing the green <kbd>+</kbd>.